# how to find key-value pairs in a dictionary based on another dictionary keys with for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I need to find the key-value pair in a dictionary, based on keys.
Could someone explain it how can it be done, please?

Sort the keys of word_freq ascendingly.
Please create a new dictionary called word_freq2 based on word_freq with the keys sorted ascendingly.

There are several ways to achieve that goal but many of the ways are beyond what we have covered so far in the course. There is one way that we'll describe employing what you have learned. Please feel free to use this way or any other way you want.

First, extract the keys of word_freq and convert it to a list called keys.

Sort the keys list.

Create an empty dictionary word_freq2.

I am not able to write the for loop for the below question. Any help would be highly appreciated
***Use a FOR loop to iterate each value in keys. For each key iterated, find the corresponding value in word_freq and insert the key-value pair to word_freq2.***

```
word_freq = {'love': 25, 'conversation': 1, 'every': 6, "we're": 1, 'plate': 1, 'sour': 1, 'jukebox': 1, 'now': 11, 'taxi': 1, 'fast': 1, 'bag': 1, 'man': 1, 'push': 3, 'baby': 14, 'going': 1, 'you': 16, "don't": 2, 'one': 1, 'mind': 2, 'backseat': 1, 'friends': 1, 'then': 3, 'know': 2, 'take': 1, 'play': 1, 'okay': 1, 'so': 2, 'begin': 1, 'start': 2, 'over': 1, 'body': 17, 'boy': 2, 'just': 1, 'we': 7, 'are': 1, 'girl': 2, 'tell': 1, 'singing': 2, 'drinking': 1, 'put': 3, 'our': 1, 'where': 1, "i'll": 1, 'all': 1, "isn't": 1, 'make': 1, 'lover': 1, 'get': 1, 'radio': 1, 'give': 1, "i'm": 23, 'like': 10, 'can': 1, 'doing': 2, 'with': 22, 'club': 1, 'come': 37, 'it': 1, 'somebody': 2, 'handmade': 2, 'out': 1, 'new': 6, 'room': 3, 'chance': 1, 'follow': 6, 'in': 27, 'may': 2, 'brand': 6, 'that': 2, 'magnet': 3, 'up': 3, 'first': 1, 'and': 23, 'pull': 3, 'of': 6, 'table': 1, 'much': 2, 'last': 3, 'i': 6, 'thrifty': 1, 'grab': 2, 'was': 2, 'driver': 1, 'slow': 1, 'dance': 1, 'the': 18, 'say': 2, 'trust': 1, 'family': 1, 'week': 1, 'date': 1, 'me': 10, 'do': 3, 'waist': 2, 'smell': 3, 'day': 6, 'although': 3, 'your': 21, 'leave': 1, 'want': 2, "let's": 2, 'lead': 6, 'at': 1, 'hand': 1, 'how': 1, 'talk': 4, 'not': 2, 'eat': 1, 'falling': 3, 'about': 1, 'story': 1, 'sweet': 1, 'best': 1, 'crazy': 2, 'let': 1, 'too': 5, 'van': 1, 'shots': 1, 'go': 2, 'to': 2, 'a': 8, 'my': 33, 'is': 5, 'place': 1, 'find': 1, 'shape': 6, 'on': 40, 'kiss': 1, 'were': 3, 'night': 3, 'heart': 3, 'for': 3, 'discovering': 6, 'something': 6, 'be': 16, 'bedsheets': 3, 'fill': 2, 'hours': 2, 'stop': 1, 'bar': 1}


keys = list(word_freq.keys())  #extract the keys of word_freq and convert it to a list called keys
print(keys)            
            
    
for i in sorted (word_freq.keys()):  #Sort the keys list.
     print(i) 
        
        
word_freq2 = {} #Create an empty dictionary word_freq2
```

Comment: for keys, values in <dict>: list.append(keys) is one way to retrieve keys from a dictionary. Read the documentation to get a full understanding on how dictionaries work: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/

Comment: hi, @Leonardo thanks for the quick reply! I need to append the word_freq2 to add the new key-value pairs actually.

Comment: thank you @Leonardo I have found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be a very simple solution after going through the [Python Dictionary Examples and Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

```
for value in keys:
    word_freq2[value] = word_freq.get(value)
print(word_freq2)
```

Python Dictionary Examples and Methods.